# Get Azure Key Valut secret, retruns null/Not Found/ Ojbect is not set

Tags: c#, azure

was able to get the secret key in my mobile app last month. However, it has stopped working. I tried all the different solutions that I found online, and each returns a different result.

Here is the code:

```
var keyClient = new KeyVaultClient(async (authority, resource, scope) =>
            {
                var adCredential = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.ClientCredential(CLIENTID, CLIENTSECRET);
                var authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority, null);
                return (await authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resource, adCredential)).AccessToken;

                });
               var secret = keyClient.GetSecretAsync(BaseURL, key, SecretKeyVerstion);
               
            return secret.Result.Value.ToString();
```

This is one of the method that I tried. I also tried the following code :

```
public  void  GetAzureUrl()
    {
        try
        {
            
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(LocalDBStorage.AzureUrls))
            {
               
                
                  keyVClient = new KeyVaultClient(new KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback(GetToken));
                var secret = await keyVClient.GetSecretAsync(SECRETURI);
              LocalDBStorage.AzureUrls = GetSecretAsync(SECRETURI);
               
               keyVClient.Dispose();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        { throw ex; }
       
    }



public string GetSecretAsync(string key)
    {
        if (Cache.TryGetValue(key, out var value))
            return value;
        else
        {

               var kv = new KeyVaultClient(new KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback(GetAccessTokenAsync));

             var secret = (kv.GetSecretAsync(App.SECRETBase)).GetAwaiter().GetResult().Value;


           
            return secret.Result.Value.ToString();
        }
    }




private async Task<string> GetAccessTokenAsync(string authority, string resource, string scope)
    {
       

        var clientId = CLIENTID;
        var clientSecret = CLIENTSECRET;
        ClientCredential clientCredential = new ClientCredential(clientId, clientSecret);

        var context = new AuthenticationContext(authority, TokenCache.DefaultShared);
        var result = await context.AcquireTokenAsync(resource, clientCredential);

        return result.AccessToken;

      
    }
```

Please advice!
Kind regards,
Kamal

Comment: Could you please catch your request?

Comment: I am sorry, I didn't understand your question. Did you mean cache the request? The error messages throw at this line:  var result = await context.AcquireTokenAsync(resource, clientCredential);

Comment: I want to get the error message in detail?

Comment: at Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.KeyVaultClient.GetSecretWithHttpMessagesAsync (System.String vaultBaseUrl, System.String secretName, System.String secretVersion, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[TKey,TValue] customHeaders, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x005ff] in <6ea39e55cc3d4eb2bd582641f96dc85f>:0 
  at Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.KeyVaultClientExtensions.GetSecretAsync (Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.IKeyVaultClient operations, System.String vaultBaseUrl, System.String secretName, System.String secretVersion, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)